# How to take backup of Jasper server 4.5 repository using js-export.bat file?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperReport server 4.5, and Jasperserver 4.5 comes default with Postgre database,
i have configured MySQL5.5 with Jasperserver and now i can connect my Jasperserver database with MySQL database and reports are working fine, but when i use js-export command to export all the Jasperserver repository report, it's showing some errors as

```
    * Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open 
     connection*
```

and

```
     *Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
       database 'jasperserver'*
```

How can i solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that you have not configured js-export correctly. Refer to the documentation and set the relevant properties file with the correct credentials (and technology!) for the repository database.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the default_master.properties file (in my case it's in the same directory as js-export) and change the database properties according to your setup.

Then js-export and js-import should work.